# DIV won't sit under slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

I cannot get my `#supportive` DIV to sit underneath it's preceding div and I'm unsure why:

[image]

I was going to solve this by adding a 'margin-top' dynamically in javascript as the slider's height will change based on the screen size however I'm certain there must be a way to do this in CSS?

***Will absolute positioning be the problem when trying to float elements 'under' each other?***

Here's the website: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4469116/new/index.html
(to reach the issue, please click on 'projects', then the first image on the top left).

Comment: It's possible (and likely) that the slider `div` is rendering as an inline element. Try adding this CSS to the `supportive` div: `{clear:both;}`

Comment: Can you provide the actual source code instead of just the image please?

Comment: You are floating both divs, which means for all effects and purposes they have a flow height of 0. Either give the first one an explicit height and `clear:both` or do that another way.[Learn about floats here.](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Comment: Extended with 2 new approaches

Comment: FYI if you put code I would have had this already solved for you

Comment: Thanks Alpha G33k - much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your slider has absolute positioning, therefore you must compensate for its height by applying a margin-top of the amount of the absolutely positioned items height, in this case it was around 380px

**Add this CSS to your stylesheet for that view:**

```
#supportive {
    margin-top: 380px;
}
```

[image: Your slider has absolute positioning, therefore your must compinsate for its height by applying a margin-top of the amount of the absolutely positioned items height, in this case it was around 380px]

Furthermore, the float is not doing anything as I can see so you should be able to remove it

If you would like your solution not fixed, the easy way with your current markup would be to give the slider a percentage height and then give a margin-top of th#e #supportive node

```
.slider {
  height: 30%;
  width: auto;
}

#supportive {
        margin-top: 30%;
 }
```

Or you can put the `.slider` inside of a separate container, and give the container the dimensions you want. This way your node will always be on the bottom as you wish as it and the container of `.slider` will be in natural flow for the document.

Comment: This solution looks good, @Alpha G33k - however I'm wondering if there's a solution that is less 'fixed' as applying a permanent margin-top as this slider changes height and width for mobile...?